# How to model many to many relationship in dynamoDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a `user` object that looks like this:

```
UserId: UUID;
Watching: Card[];
Stocks: Stock [];
Listing: Card[];
```

And then I have a `Card` object that looks like this:

```
CardId: UUID;
UserId: UUID;
… other card attributes i.e name
```

And a `stock` Object that looks like this:

```
CardId: UUID;
UserId: UUID;
Price: string;
Quantity: string;
Timestamp: string;
```

My access patterns look like:

- Get a list of cards belonging to user
- Get a list of cards a user is watching
- Get a list of stocks a user owns

The first access pattern is straight forward as it would just be a `PK` of `CardId` and `SK` of `UserId`

But I am unsure on my second - usually in relational databases I would add a watching Table. And I was thinking I could create a watching entity with a `userId` and `CardId` And then have a GSI to get the card related to that watching item but this doesn’t feel right to me following single table design.

This is similar to my third access pattern, I have created a separate entity as a stock has different information to a card but they all feel similar.

Is there a better way to model a many to many relationship like this such as having a `PK` of `CardId` and `SK` of `UserId`. But with different items coming back?

Any help with this would be great! Thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand what a stock. Is a card a physical card like a baseball card? With one owner? That might be offered for sale? I see a CardID has a UUID and a quantity both, so a CardID is more like a SKU? But if a CardID is a SKU then why do you model it with an owner? It might have more than one owner?

Comment: I am trying to make a mock stock exchange for cards for a course I’m doing. So I see a card as a company. And a stock as someone’s holding. Which has all the cards attributes which is why I want to do a GSI to get the card. But has additional information such as the quantity held, the price bought at.

Comment: On my stock exchange users can create their own cards to list on the exchange. Therefore a card can have a creator - which would be the user. So only one user can create the card. But many users can watch the card. 
Then a user can own many stocks from many cards.

Answer (score 2):

All your access patterns are based on user-id, which hints that you want the user-id to be the primary key for all the tables (cards, stocks...). It can also be a good security mechanism to make sure that nobody can access the information of other users.

The main "trick" should be on the `stocks` table as you might have a lot of duplications on the combinations of cards (companies) and stocks if a user can buy and sell different cards and stocks over time. This `stocks` table can have the following structure:

```
user-id (primary key)
timestamp (sort key)
card
stock
price
```

On this table, you can define a couple of indexes (GSI or LSI) for `user-card` and `user-stock`

Comment: This has been really useful thank you! 
Just so I’m clear in terms of get all cards a user watches. Would it be a case of making the watching attribute store an array of CardIds and a GSI with say a PK of CardId and a SK of Watching?

Comment: Or is it just as simple as being able to query a user and then get the array of cards they are watching. I think I’ve been trying to over think it and think more about storage!

Comment: You can have also a `cards` table with all the cards of each user-id and some additional meta-data on that card and user relationships (start-date, etc.). You can derive it from the main `stocks` table, but it can also have additional meta-data that you can keep in each relationship record.